# Linux Alternative for Netclean?

Tags: web, filter

I am looking for an alternative for blocking Child Sex Abuse content within the Enterprise environment.

Or

Is there any way i could have a link to the database containing hashes for the digital fingerprint which i can compare to what employees in my organization are accessing through a browser or on their laptop clients?

There is a tool called " NetClean" but it does not have any compatibility for linux if deployed on client side.

Answer (score 0):

The one that I'm the most familiar with is [DansGuardian](http://dansguardian.org/). The other approach you could take would be to setup a Squid Proxy and use [Squickblacklists.org](http://www.squidblacklist.org/) to incorporate high quality blacklists.

Lastly I'd take a look at the extensive Q&A's over on AskUbuntu titled: [What is the best way to restrict access to adult content?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158572/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-adult-content).